# Detection Issue of Default.theme File in Java Netbeans Platform Application

Tags: java, hsqldb, netbeans-8

I am developing a Netbeans Platform Application using Java 8 and Netbeans IDE 8.2, utilizing the hsqldb database handler. I have generated its installer for the Windows operating system. However, upon installation and startup of the application, there are instances where it fails to detect the Default.theme file. This file contains the aesthetic configuration (Look And Feel) of the application, including font size, background color, toolbar color, etc., and is built using TinyLaf. It is located at C:\Program Files\rocky. Consequently, the application launches without this configuration.

When I open the app, sometimes it doesn't display the aesthetic configuration, so I have to close and reopen it. I want to open the app detecting the file Default.theme without issues.thanks for yours answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.